# no reconoce el bean de un parametro de funcion en rest

Tags: java, spring, rest

estoy intentando aprender rest de la guia en [spring.io](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/rest/), al seguir los pasos para levantar un proyecto hay algunas diferencias con respecto al proyecto (como el paquete que tiene otro nombre y que el import de javax no me lo toma pero el jakarta si) pero al momento de cargar unos datos y mostrar por consola, me marca que no se puede crear un bean:
[image: foto]
el proyecto compila y ejecuta, pero no ejecuta los 2 comandos que tendria que ejecutar nomas corra el proyecto y no sale nada por consola, alguien sabe que puede ser?

EmployeeRepository.java

```
package com.payroll.repository;

import com.payroll.entity.Employee;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface EmployeeRepository extends JpaRepository<Employee, Long> {}
```

Employee.java

```
package com.payroll.entity;

import java.util.Objects;
import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class Employee{

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Long id;
private String name;
private String role;

public Employee(String name, String role){
    this.name = name;
    this.role = role;
}

public Employee() {

}

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getRole() {
    return role;
}

public void setRole(String role) {
    this.role = role;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {

    if (this == o)
        return true;
    if (!(o instanceof Employee))
        return false;
    Employee employee = (Employee) o;
    return Objects.equals(this.id, employee.id) && Objects.equals(this.name, employee.name)
            && Objects.equals(this.role, employee.role);
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return Objects.hash(this.id, this.name, this.role);
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Employee{" + "id=" + this.id + ", name='" + this.name + '\'' + ", role='" + this.role + '\'' + '}';
}

}
```

LoadDatabase.java

```
package com.payroll.database;

import com.payroll.entity.Employee;
import com.payroll.repository.EmployeeRepository;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class LoadDatabase {
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoadDatabase.class);


    @Bean
    CommandLineRunner initDatabase(EmployeeRepository repository){
        return args -> {
            log.info("Preloading " + repository.save(new Employee("Bilbo Baggins", "burglar")));
            log.info("Preloading " + repository.save(new Employee("Frodo Baggins", "thief")));
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: te recomiendo hacer el [tour]

Comment: puedes poner completo tu Employee? Algo me dice que te faltó alguna anotación o ponerle setters y getters

Comment: ya puse el codigo de empoyee